# Port forwarding with iptables does not work for commands send directly from console

Tags: iptables

I have set up following ip tables rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --dst 192.168.0.116  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000


sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             static.snake2.test tcp dpt:www redir   ports 8000

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination

That will forward any traffic on port 80 on the given ip to port 8000 on the same ip. Works perfectly through a browser.

What does not work is, if I try to run some test directly from console:

lynx -head -dump http://192.168.0.116

or what I intended to do

```
ab -n 1000 -c20 192.168.0.116
```

In that case the forwarding rule simply does not work. The header given back is still from port 80 (apache) and not like expected from nginx (8000).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to contain the contents of `iptables -L`?

Comment: I have just added the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the reason you are seeing this is that the PREROUTING chain is not applicable to the packets that go via the loopback interface.  When you say it works from a browser, I assume you mean from another machine, in which case your rule will apply.  You'll need to add a rule to the OUTPUT chain too to get it to work on the localhost traffic.  Something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --source 0/0 --destination 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

Comment: you are right! 
    neptun:~$ lynx -head -dump http://192.168.0.116
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx

    @snake2:~$ lynx -head -dump http://192.168.0.116
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2012 17:12:04 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e

Do you know how I can add a rule to the OUTPUT chain to make that work?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I would expect something like the rule I added above would do it.

Comment: Perfect! Works excellent. Thank you for your help.

Comment: excellent :) if you can accept the answer I'd appreciate it - need the help on the rep front ;)